# How to disable 'enclosure' custom field link from appearing in the post

Tags: custom-field, video-player

Seems like there is no way to delete the custom field 'enclosure' (if I delete it in a post, as soon as I press update it will appear again).

OK, but how can I remove the link to the video file (my-vide.flv), which is added automatically in the post? (this custom field adds it when a video is present in the post)

I have no code that would call this custom field.

Can't find anything on the internet about this. I just found a code to remove the direct link to the video (which allows downloads) from feeds, but not from the post itself.

Comment: your theme or a plugin is doing this, you'll have to figure out where it's happening and ask whomever wrote the theme/plugin.

Comment: so it's not Wordpress which is adding the custom field? Hmm that's interesting, I read that WP was doing this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "enclosure";
```

Open the MYSQL database window. Select the database. Open the SQL code insert window. Add this code in the text box. Click the GO button. The problem is solved.